# Verifying an rpm package integrity

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, rpm, dnf

I'm trying to verify the integrity of packages using `rpm -K` command, but whatever I type it says "No such file or directory",  although the packages are installed

```
[anonymous@vendetta ~]$ rpm -q openssh-server
openssh-server-8.8p1-7.fc37.x86_64 
[anonymous@vendetta ~]$ rpm --checksig openssh-server
error: openssh-server: open failed: No such file or directory
[anonymous@vendetta ~]$ 
[anonymous@vendetta ~]$ rpm -K openssh-server
error: openssh-server: open failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you wanting to check the integrity of the **installed** versions of the files provided by the package or the integrity of the rpm file prior to installing it?

Comment: Thanks for your response, i want to check the integrity of the rpm file prior to installing it

Comment: You need to give the rpm filename, not the package name to `rpm -K`.

Comment: Thanks sir, one last thing what is the difference between a package and the rpm file? like isn't supposed to be the same thing ?

Comment: The package is contained in a file. For the sake of my sanity I give files a name that is related to the contents of the file, e.g. addressbook.txt, birthdays.txt, disk_serial_numbers, ... I **could** have the openssh-server package stored in a file called gcc.rpm. (For more discussion on the difference between something, what the name is, and what it is called see https://www.gutenberg.org/files/12/12-h/12-h.htm#link2HCH0008 Alice through the looking glass).. To get rpm to check the contents of a file you have to give it the name of the file, not the name of the package contained in it.

Answer (score 3):

To check the integrity of or otherwise verify an rpm file before it is installed, then the
following is used with the rpm file itself. This is `openssh-server` for Fedora 37 which you are using:

```
rpm -K openssh-server-8.8p1-7.fc37.x86_64.rpm
```

You'll either need to use `wget` or `curl` to download it from the repo URL online or use `yum install --downloadonly`.

To verify a package that is already installed:

```
rpm -V openssh-server
```

The output will give a legend regarding any of the files that have changed since the installation:

```
   S file Size differs  
   M Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)  
   5 MD5 sum differs  
   D Device major/minor number mismatch  
   L readLink(2) path mismatch  
   U User ownership differs  
   G Group ownership differs  
   T mTime differs  
   P caPabilities differ

   ? Missing
```

In the case of my Fedora 37 VM, it gives the following output because I've changed the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

S.5....T.  c /etc/ssh/sshd_config

From the legend, that means the file size, MD5 sum, and mTime have changed since the package installed.

Comment: @TheRoguePrince If the repo file has the gpgcheck enabled and the gpgkey file, then  `yum` or `dnf` will verify it beforehand. That is why it exists: to avoid having the verify the signature of every single package. If one insists on doing it manually for the package itself, then it's necessary to use one of the methods that I've provided or run the `rpm -K` command on the URL to the rpm file itself: `rpm -K https://repo.almalinux.org/almalinux/9/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/openssh-server-8.7p1-24.el9_1.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! :)

Comment: One last thing, everything is clear now except : what is the difference between a package and the rpm file? like isn't supposed to be the same thing ?

Comment: @TheRoguePrince One is looking at the rpm file itself whereas the other is looking at what's in the rpm database which, in the case of Fedora and its derivatives, is located in /var/lib/rpm